# How is free energy built into a Metropolis Monte Carlo simulation of an Ising model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

In the Metropolis algorithm, the change in the energy given by the hamiltonian is compared for flipping a spin. This is not the free energy, but for systems above absolute zero you are trying to minimize the free energy, not the energy. So how is free energy built into this kind of simulation? How is entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert on this, so I would appreciate if errors are pointed out.

To my understanding, the difference between the total energy and the free energy is due to statistical mechanics. Your simulation works on the level of the smallest constituents of the system, and doesn't directly look for the lowest energy configuration, but samples the space of all configurations with a probability for each state that is a function of its energy and the temperature. All statistical phenomena should automatically emerge from this.

For example, a state that is qualitatively equal to many other states (essentially corresponding to a macrostate with high entropy) will be sampled more often than a state of lower energy that is very unlikely. The transition from a lower energy state to this higher energy state should happen in your simulation exactly when the associated free energy change negative, which will depend on temperature.